# Mandelbrot function using bitwise operators

Tags: c, fractals, bit-manipulation

I'm rendering buddhabrot fractals and I'm looking for some optimisations/speedups and I was wondering if it could be worth while trying to do z = z^2 + c using bitwise operators. I've allready simplified it down a bit.

```
   double zi2 = z.i*z.i;
   double zr2 = z.r*z.r;
   double zir = z.i*z.r;
   while (iterations < MAX_BUDDHA_ITERATIONS && zi2 + zr2 < 4) {

         z.i = c.i;
         z.i += zir;
         z.i += zir;
         z.r = zr2 - zi2 + c.r;
         zi2 = z.i*z.i;
         zr2 = z.r*z.r;
         zir = z.i*z.r;
         iterations++;
   }
```

Comment: What language are you using? If it is VM based (java or c# for example) it is probably counter productive...

Comment: I'm using C programming and thats what I was thinking. Is it going to be worth while, and how.

Comment: What do you mean by "It must be possible because the compiler does it..."? If the compiler optimizes it, why dou you want to do it in the source?

Comment: The computer works in 1's and 0's so it must brake it all down and do its calculations essentialy like that anyway. The compiler will optimise it but it may not be as effective as it could be.

Comment: No, it would not be worth it.

Comment: I think I was getting a bit confused and I've fixed my question. Only in highschool and I'm still new to computing so sorry.

Comment: Are you confusing assembler / machine code with bitwise operations?

Comment: This has actually cleared up a lot of confusion for me.

Comment: @JordanBrown, there are a few things you might find it interesting to research: storage of integers (signed and unsigned), storage of floating-point numbers ("double" is a floating-point type). Assembly language would also help. Compilers turn high-level instructions into assembly language instructions; some will even let you save the generated assembly code (gcc's `-S` flag, for example). Breaking down a complex operation can even backfire. Doing it manually can the compiler's hand, rather than letting it choose which optimization may be appropriate for a high-level operation.

Comment: It might be worth looking at using the C99 built in complex number support, it's likely to be both faster and more numerically accurate than hand rolled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z^2+c` can be encapsulated in the [fused multiply-accumulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) operation. This is available as single instruction on some processors and is becoming available on others. In processors where it is not available, it is usually optimized or optimizeable. For instance, C99 defines the [fma](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.bpxbd00/fma.htm) family of functions to provide it. So I'd say that what you want is probably happening already and, if it's not, there's a very readable way to guarantee that it is.

In general, you should be highly suspicious any time your subconscious whispers that it would be faster to replace readable, maintainable code with a less-readable, less-maintainable, more difficult to debug solution X which you have just dreamed up. Readability and maintainability are extremely important not just for writing code well, but for sharing it and for talking about its correctness; computers are fast, compilers are pretty decent.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not do it in bitwise operations... It's CPU and its ALU which use bitwise operations, which happen in parallel for all bits of a word of course, even multiple machine code instructuons (like multipy) at a time in modern processors.

What you are asking makes no sense... Well, if you are programming an FPGA, it might make some sense, but I assume you are not...